# "Как за каменной стеной" — статус оборота

Tags: пунктуация, фразеология, запятые, как, сравнительный-оборот

Вот русская поговорка (с двумя вариантами пунктуации):
*За добрым мужем, **как за каменной стеной,** за худым мужем и забора нет.

За добрым мужем **как за каменной стеной,** за худым мужем — и забора нет.*

Вот что сообщает [фразеологический словарь](https://phrase_dictionary.academic.ru/1030/%D0%9A%D0%90%D0%9A_%D0%97%D0%90_%D0%9A%D0%90%D0%9C%D0%95%D0%9D%D0%9D%D0%9E%D0%99_%D0%A1%D0%A2%D0%95%D0%9D%D0%9E%D0%99).
КАК ЗА КАМЕННОЙ СТЕНОЙ
**кто** быть; жить, чувствовать себя
В полной безопасности, под покровительством, под надёжной защитой.
*Говорится* с одобрением; реч. стандарт; неизм. В роли именной части сказ. или обст. Порядок слов-компонентов фиксир.

Примеры употребления из словарной статьи (с запятой и без):
*...я тебе помогу, ты за мной, как за каменной стеной.

Ты, говорит военком, будешь за ним как за каменной стеной.

Экспедиция за ним, как за каменной стеной.

Я всю жизнь прожила за Володей как за каменной стеной.*

**Так КАК же определить**, в каком случае выделять оборот запятыми, а в каком — нет?

Comment: "Я всю жизнь прожила за Володей, как за каменной стеной" — с запятой здесь: http://lib.ru/PROZA/LEWASHOW/codex04.txt_with-big-pictures.html

Comment: "Ты, говорит военком, будешь за ним, как за каменной стеной" — с запятой здесь: http://www.lib.ru/PROZA/FEDIN/neoleto.txt

Comment: Я не смотрела пунктуацию _в других_ источниках, т. к. привела в вопросе выдержки из словарной статьи - как примеры. Меня и заинтересовал этот принцип: обособляем фразеологический оборот или нет? Как же правильно порешить?

Answer (score 2):

Оборот ***как за каменной стеной*** имеет значение обстоятельства — в полной безопасности, под надёжной защитой.

Он используется в различных конструкциях: с повтором падежной формы (***за*** ним, ***за*** каменной стеной) и без повтора. В первом случае оборот может обособляться или не обособляться; во втором случае он обычно не обособляется.

Ну вот, чувствуйте себя как дома, ― полковник хозяйским жестом обвел рукой свои владения. ― **У нас как за каменной стеной.** Бояться вам тут абсолютно нечего. [Андрей Геласимов. Дом на Озерной (2009)]

Обособление оборота связано **с интонационной структурой** предложения.

1) **Оборот  обособляется,** если предыдущее слово выделено логическим ударением, причем слово с ударением обычно смещено относительно союза КАК (тогда после него следует пауза):

За **дОбрым** мужем, **как за каменной стеной**, за худым мужем и забора нет.

Я тебе помогу, **тЫ** за мной, **как за каменной стеной**.

**ЭкспедИция** за ним, **как за каменной стеной**.

2) **Оборот  не обособляется**, если на предыдущем сочетании нет ударения, тогда пауза не делается:

Ты, говорит военком, будешь за ним **как за каменной стенОй.**

Я всю жизнь прожила за Володей **как за каменной стенОй.**

Таким образом, автор может обособить оборот или не обособлять его, но при этом он должен **выбрать соответствующую структуру** предложения. Для читателя структура является уже готовой, поэтому он должен правильно прочитать предложение.

Comment: "Я всю жизнь прожила за Володей, как за каменной стеной" - с запятой здесь: http://lib.ru/PROZA/LEWASHOW/codex04.txt_with-big-pictures.html

Comment: "Ты, говорит военком, будешь за ним, как за каменной стеной" - с запятой здесь: http://www.lib.ru/PROZA/FEDIN/neoleto.txt

Comment: В некоторых случаях структура предложения предполагает два варианта прочтения. Может выделить ударением предыдущее слово, и тогда при чтении нужно будет сделать паузу и обозначить ее запятой. Я всю жизнь прожила за ВолОдей, как за каменной стенОй. Ты, говорит военком, будешь за нИм, как за каменной стенОй.

Answer (score 1):

Вот что говорится у Розенталя.

Примечания:

1. Запятая в этих случаях обычно отсутствует, если сравнительный оборот **выступает в роли сказуемого.** Когда же речь идет **именно о сравнительном обороте, то в одинаковых условиях запятая может быть, а может и не быть. Ср.:**

Вечер был **как две капли воды** похож на всякий другой вечер (Л.Т.). — На Матвея с обеих сторон улицы глядели занавешенные окна домов, похожих друг на друга, **как две капли воды** (Кор.);

Сальные свечи… **берегли как зеницу ока (С.-Щ.).** — Надо, **как зеницу ока,** хранить память о лучших людях своей страны;

Отсюда вся громадная территория порта обычно была **видна как на ладони (Кат.).** — С вершины все окрестности были видны, **как на ладони (Закр.);*

За таким фельдфебелем командир роты **как у Христа за пазухой (Брык.). —** Благодарите Всевышнего, что сидите у болота, **как у Христа за пазухой (Ш.).**

2. Вопрос о пунктуации при сравнительных оборотах, в частности при сравнениях идиоматического характера, не может решаться в отрыве от характера самих оборотов (сравнения общеязыкового типа или художественные сравнения, иногда индивидуально-авторские), состава устойчивых сочетаний, как он представлен в толковых и фразеологических словарях, и т. д.[9]

Как видно, запятая не ставится, если оборот является частью сказуемого.

Comment: @Slava1947,  думаю одно, пишу другое. Конечно же, запятая не нужна, если оборот является частью сказуемого.

Answer (score 1):

Логично было бы построить предложение симметрично, с двумя тире (за добрым мужем — как за каменной стеной, за худым мужем — и забора нет), но такой вариант отсутствует в интернете. Категорически не нравится мне вариант с запятой. У него смысл не обобщения, а описания конкретной ситуации (я удачно вышла замуж и теперь за добрым мужем, как за каменной стеной).

Comment: @ М_Г, видимо стоит признать, что оборот "как за каменной стеной" испытывает колебания.

Comment: @Серж, Думаю, дело в том, что в поговорке не сравнительный оборот, а сказуемое, поэтому запятая неуместна.

Answer (score 0):

Это не сравнительный оборот, поэтому и запятая не нужна в любом случае. И в поговорке тоже. В ней лучше, наверное, два раза поставить тире.